# Text is Squashed at runtime Nokia Lumia 640

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

When on my emyulator the text looks fine but when looking at it on a lumia 640 at runtime its looking squashed as in the pic is their anyway to tell texblox to automatically grow like you do in a webpage with paragraph tag?.

```
<PivotItem x:Name="pivot_item1" Header="movie details" Margin="10,-76,28,-20.833" Loaded="pivot_item1_Loaded">
            <StackPanel Height="505">
                <ProgressRing Name="BusyProgressRing" IsActive="False"></ProgressRing>

                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,118" Height="514"  >
                    <TextBlock FontSize="13" x:Name="txtTtile" Text="{Binding name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,26,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="212" Foreground="White" Height="29" SelectionChanged="txtTtile_SelectionChanged"/>
                    <Image Grid.Row="2" x:Name="moveImage"  Source="{Binding image}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="186" Margin="19,26,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="112"/>
                    <TextBlock    FontSize="13" x:Name="txtPlot" Text="{Binding Description}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,217,-28,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="371" Foreground="White" Height="140" SelectionChanged="txtTtile_SelectionChanged" SelectionHighlightColor="White"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" FontSize="13" x:Name="txtTtile_Copy1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,196,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="212" Foreground="White" Height="29" SelectionChanged="txtTtile_SelectionChanged" Text="SYNOPSIS"/>

                    <TextBlock FontSize="13" x:Name="lblrating" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,362,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" Foreground="White" Height="29" SelectionChanged="txtTtile_SelectionChanged" Text="Rating"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="13" x:Name="lblduration" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,425,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="104" Foreground="White" Height="29" SelectionChanged="txtTtile_SelectionChanged" Text="Duration"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="13" x:Name="txtCategory" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="177,425,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="104" Foreground="White" Height="29" SelectionChanged="txtTtile_SelectionChanged" Text="Category"/>

                    <TextBlock FontSize="13" x:Name="lblcategory" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="248,425,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="104" Foreground="White" Height="29" SelectionChanged="txtTtile_SelectionChanged" Text="{Binding Category}"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="13" x:Name="txtduration" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="76,425,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" Foreground="White" Height="29" SelectionChanged="txtTtile_SelectionChanged" Text="{Binding Duration}"/>


            </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
</PivotItem>
```

Is their anyway to make sure it pushes the other controls down ??

[image]

**Edit**
Ok so I have changed to using the grid system but now my text looks even more sqaushed what can i do to solve this and their appears to be an inital gap above as well i cant  seem to get rid off i just want the  post to be just below the words movie details.

```
<Pivot x:Name="myPivot">
        <PivotItem x:Name="pvtMoveDetails" Header="movie details" Margin="10,-76,28,-20.833" >
            <StackPanel Height="505">
                <ProgressRing Name="BusyProgressRing" IsActive="False"></ProgressRing>

                <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border  x:Name="brdElement" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">

                    <Image x:Name="moveImage"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Source="{Binding image}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="186"    Width="112"/>

                    </Border>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="13" x:Name="txtTtile" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="212" Foreground="White" Height="29" SelectionChanged="txtTtile_SelectionChanged" Text="txttitle"/>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Description"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"   FontSize="13" x:Name="txtPlot" Text="{Binding Description}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="371" Foreground="White" Height="247" SelectionChanged="txtTtile_SelectionChanged" SelectionHighlightColor="White"/>



                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
 </PivotItem>
```

After changing to grid system ?

[image]

**NOTE FOR MORE**

I did what you said changed to a grid row system but the text is still not showing full how do i give the impression to the end user their is more text to come

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're using fixed places and margins to place your controls. This would only look good on screens with the same exact size as the one you wrote it for.
XAML works best with it's [flow layout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465337.aspx), and to do that, you need to use `Panels`. There are several, `Grid`, `StackPanel`, and `Canvas` to name a few. Each presents it's children differently.

For example `Grid` let's you arrange you controls in a table, and `StackPanel` places the controls one after another in a single column/row.

Read this tutorial, and you should get the hang of it in no time: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140613/WPF-Tutorial-Layout-Panels-Containers-Layout-Trans#heading0005.

Comment: please see edut above mate